# Columns visibility using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

Say I have these columns in my report:

```
foo
bar
fum
baz
```

Say that I want to conditionally display this columns based on a toggle item and  a specific expression. Also, I want SSRS to collapse the columns for the currently-hidden items. So initially I see:

```
+foo baz
```

Then, if I click on the + beside foo, I see:

```
-foo bar fum baz
```

Can that be done in ssrs? If so, how?
Currently when I click + I get

```
-bar fum
```

Comment: Can you give some more info on the setup e.g. is it a table or a tablix/matrix, and are the columns a group?

Comment: @StephLocke it is a tablix and the columns is not a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the visibility for numerous textboxes (so all the columns you want to hide) toggle based on a single textbox in the Visibility tab for the textboxes and setting the `Display can be toggled by this report item` option to the `foo` column header.

You'll need to be careful to get them all right and set them all (`bar`, `fum`) by default to hidden.  Since you've already tried to set it, I'd recommend starting your table from scratch and trying to do it a column at a time as you may have some legacy values ticked somewhere that are making things difficult for you.

It sounds like you know what you're doing but here's an in-depth on the topic if you'd like a walkthrough: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405.aspx